# If $\omega^i = \omega$ then $\omega = \epsilon$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that If $\omega^i = \omega$ then $\omega = \epsilon$, for every i , $i$ is an integer $\ge 0$ , $\epsilon$ is an empty string and $\omega$ is a word over some alphabet.

I have trouble thinking about ideas regarding this proof. My intuition tells me to prove this by contradiction. Suppose $\omega^i = \omega$ and $\omega \neq \epsilon$. Therefore, $|\omega| \gt 0$.

How can I go about continuing this proof ?

Comment: Presumably $i \ne 1$?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: For any word $\omega$, $\omega^1 = \omega$; therefore, the problem as stated is not true unless you add the restriction that $i \ne 1$.

Comment: suppose w= ab. then ab^i won't always result in ab. It will result in $\epsilon$ , ab, abab, ababab etc..

Comment: You're on the right track! For $i \not = 1$, how does $| \omega^i |$ compare to $| \omega|$? Why does this show that $\omega = \epsilon$?

Comment: Is stating : "$w^i$ means that string w is concatenated with itself $i \ge 0$ times. The only string that can undergo multiple concatenations with itself and reduce to the same word we started with is indeed $\epsilon$. " , enough ?

Comment: When are two words equal? Can we "simplify from the left"? (...or right) Simpler argument: Can we use the length of a word? Please also change the posted question, so that the case $i=1$ is eliminated, as above, we have "many" (any word but one) counterexamples in this case...

Comment: Your wording is ambiguous. Is your assumption that $\omega^i=\omega$ for **some** integer $i\ge0$, is is it that $\omega^i=\omega$ for **every** integer $i\ge0$? If you mean **some** $i$ the statement is false: $\omega^1=\omega$ does not imply anything very interesting about $\omega$. If you mean **every** integer $i\ge0$ the statement is trivial: $\omega^0=\omega$ already implies that $\omega$ is the empty string.-

Comment: The case is supposed to include i = 1.For every i, the condition above must hold true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting w = length $\omega$, by hypothesis iw = w.
If i > 1, then w = 0.
If i = 1, then w can be any natural number.
If i = 0, then w = 0.

Thus if i /= 1, $\omega = \epsilon.$

Comment: Thank you this makes me understand the problem more!!